# Who is going to PICC?

Tags: discussion

As [PICC](http://PICConf.org)( Professional IT Community Conference by LOPSA-NJ) draws near, I figure it would be interesting to see how many "Serverfaulters"will be going and who I'd be running into. I'm going, and I'd put money that I'm the youngest attendee.

Comment: I've seen other conference stuff on meta here before, does it not belong?

Comment: Never heard of it, maybe you give us a short-story information what this is?
Youngest? Nevermind checked your profile.

Comment: @muazam Post that on the main site.